# Tablet not connecting to my home wifi router

Tags: wi-fi, tablet

I have a micromax funbook p300 tablet with a custom rom installed android ver 4.1.1
Before some days it was connecting to my wifi router. But now it is not getting connected to the router, though it can find the wifi network. I have tried to factory reset many times. And the rom I am using is bug free and has no issues with wifi connectivity. pls help

Comment: Have you hard reset the router?

Comment: Yes many times. My router is TPLink WR743ND v2

Comment: Check router mode (b/g/n/ac), change channel (1,6,11)